# Prevent direct access to specific port in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx to reverse proxy to serve content of 8090 port to 443
Every thing works fine e.g. if i open http://example.com it redirect to https://example.com

But problem http://example.com:8090 is still accessible without SSL, is there any way to restrict or redirect

```
#-------- To redirect to ssl -------     
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen      443 default;
        server_name example.com;

        proxy_buffers 16 64k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;

        # ------ some ssl config --------

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8090;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        }
    }
```

Comment: iptables is often used to such purpose.

Comment: thanks i thought about that, just want to know is there any way in nginx

Comment: There isn't, nothing nginx can do about that.

Comment: Reconfigure your application to no longer listen to all addresses.